# Get verb is not calling to correct action

Tags: c#, ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have two get verbs in the same controller, so I'm trying to call one of them but it calls the other one. I want to call `GetCoCDropdownOptionsAction` but it is always calling `GetCoCCallLogHistory`

I have tried renaming the action methods, sending the id but it continue looking for the first verb (the one that has id parameter)

```
//In the controller ABCController.cs
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetCoCCallLogHistory")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCoCCallLog(string code, int id)
{

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetCoCDropdownOptionsAction")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCoCDropdownOptions(string code)

//Routing
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AllowingMultipleGetsId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{code}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", id= RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { code= "[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)?" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AllowingMultipleGets",
    routeTemplate: "api/{code}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home" },
    constraints: new { code = "[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)?" }
);

//In the javascript using angularjs
$http.get('/api/' + $scope.code + 
'/ABC/GetCoCDropdownOptionsAction').then(function (response) {
        //...
    }, function (response) {
        //...
    });
```

I'm receiving this error message:

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetCoCCallLog(System.String, Int32)' in 'xxx.ABCController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}
```

Please provide any help of if you need more information let me know.

Comment: Try changing `int id`  to `int? id`.

Comment: Did you intend for id to be optional? You've said it's optional in the route config but youve made it not optional by making it int. which is it?

Comment: I want to call GetCoCDropdownOptionsAction but it is calling GetCoCCallLogHistory

Comment: What is the request url according to the server logging?

Comment: Not sure if you mean this: http://localhost:44331/api/xxx/ABC/GetCoCDropdownOptionsAction

Comment: Change `{id}` to `{id?}` in the first maphttproute, and remove the second maphttproute. If that doesn't work, I don't think the code you've shown here is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I have another route that was above, so it was looking at that before.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "xsx",
            routeTemplate: "api/{code}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { marketCode = "[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)?" }
        );
```

I just change the order and that solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message points out,

`id` which is of `System.Int32` i.e. a value type is getting a value of null which is not possible, the default value for int is 0 and **not null**.

To made `id` to have the possibility of being `null` you need to make it as a `nullable type`.

To do that change this action:-

> GetCoCCallLog(string code, int? id)

Comment: I don't have any issues trying to call GetCoCCallLog, the problem is that I'm trying to call GetCoCDropdownOptionsAction, what am I doing wrong? I tried what you suggested me though, there is no error now but I want to call the other method.